# ActionListener reset variable's current value to default

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compare, actionlistener

I'm working on a project for a simple game where you can go to different rooms by using buttons (north, east, west, south). Within the makeFrame() method of my gui I'm creating the panel, buttons etc. I then set the default room to "hall" for example and the actionlistener calls the method goRoom and passing the direction and currentRoom to that method. The goRoom method change the currentRoom to another room depending on the currentRoom. I included print statements to see if it works and so far it works fine.

Everytime the game starts the default room is the hall.
So when you click a button to go for example "North", the northButton is called in which then we call the goRoom method passing the direction (north) and the default room "hall" (as the game just starts and uses the default room).
Then the room changes from hall to state room (within the method goRoom). When I try to press another button the currentRoom reset to the default value (hall).

I think the action listener get the value from the makeFrame() method instead of the updated value from the goRoom method. The code is below:

```
public class StoreGUI extends JFrame
{
    public String currentRoom;

    public StoreGUI()
    {
        makeFrame();
    }


    private void makeFrame()
    { 
        currentRoom = "hall";
        ....


        northButton = new JButton("Go North");
        northButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                                   direction = "north";
                                   goRoom(direction, currentRoom); }
                           });
        toolbar.add(northButton);

        westButton ....
        southButton ....      
        eastButton ....

        picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/hall.png"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(picture);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

private void goRoom(String direction, String currentRoom)
    {
        // get current room and check which direction button the user has pressed
        if (direction == "north"){
            if(currentRoom == "hall"){
                // Inserts the image icon and change currentRoom
                imgageTitle = "image/stateRoom.png";
                currentRoom = "stateRoom";
            }
            ....
}
```

What the problem could be? How can I fix that? I'm pretty sure it's something really simple but I'm stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` comparison in Java is done with `String#equals` not `==`.  This will compare the actual text of the `String` and not its memory reference...

For example, instead of

```
if (direction == "north") {....
```

Use

```
if ("north".equals(direction)) {...
```

If you don't care about the case, you could use...

```
if ("north".equalsIgnoreCase(direction)) {...
```

Having said all that, you could actually use a `enum` to represent the directions, which restricts what values you can actually pass to the `goRoom`.

You could also use a [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to define each button's actions, which also means you could use them [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) or [menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) without having to duplicate any code...but that's just me...

**Updated**

You're also shadowing your values...

```
private void goRoom(String direction, String currentRoom)
{
    //...
    currentRoom = "stateRoom";
```

Changing the value of `currentRoom` will have no effect beyond the scope of the method.  This is because you're not actually changing the content of the `String` object, but changing it's memory reference.

Instead, either change the name of the parameter or, simply don't bother passing, as you already have access to the instance field of the same name...

```
private void goRoom(String direction)
{
    //...
    currentRoom = "stateRoom";
```

Comment: I tried both but I got the same problem. It keeps changing the current room to the default one. As I said  I used print statements and it prints that the current room is hall. then when the goRoom is called it prints the new room (let's say state room). But when I'm trying to press another button it change the new room to the default one.

Comment: thank you so much. It took me 5 days and I didn't even notice that.